# TSQL recursive CTE order

Tags: t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am having trouble figuring out how I can use recursive CTEs to order my results recursively. Here is what I mean (this is a simplified dataset):

I have this as input:

```
declare @sections table (id int, parent int);

insert into @sections values (1, 1);
insert into @sections values (2, 2);
insert into @sections values (3, 2);
insert into @sections values (4, 2);
insert into @sections values (5, 4);
insert into @sections values (6, 1);
insert into @sections values (7, 6);
insert into @sections values (8, 6);
insert into @sections values (9, 6);
insert into @sections values (10, 9);

-- hierarchical view
--1
--  6
--      7
--      8
--          10
--      9
--2
--  3
--  4
--      5
```

And I want this as output
**EDIT: The order of the rows is the important part here**

```
--  id  parent  depth
--  1   1       0
--  6   1       1
--  7   6       2
--  8   6       2
-- 10   8       3
--  9   6       2
--  2   2       0
```

This is the best I can do:

```
with section_cte as
(
    select id, parent, 0 'depth' from @sections where id = parent
    union all
    select cte.id, cte.parent, depth + 1 
    from @sections s join section_cte cte on s.parent = cte.id where s.id <> s.parent
)
select *from section_cte
```

Can anyone please help me tweak this query to get what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain little bit output

Comment: Why have you chosen a scheme where root level items are parents of themselves? It is usual for these to have null parents.

Comment: @MartinSmith In our system, the root levels are where id = parent. That is why the mock data is this way

Comment: @TheGameiswar The order of the rows in the output is as if the tree was traversed recursively depth first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick you need is to create a sortstring which match your business rule. Something like this.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    id, parent, 0 AS depth
    --For MS SQL Server 2012+
    ,cast(format(id,'0000') as varchar(max)) sort
    --For previous versions
    ,cast(stuff('0000',5-len(cast(id as varchar)),len(cast(id as varchar)),id) as varchar(max)) sort1
FROM @sections
WHERE id=parent
UNION ALL
SELECT s.id, s.parent, c.depth + 1
    ,sort + cast(format(s.id,'0000') as varchar(max)) sort
    ,sort + cast(stuff('0000',5-len(cast(s.id as varchar)),len(cast(s.id as varchar)),s.id) as varchar(max)) sort1
FROM @sections s
    inner join CTE c ON s.parent=c.id AND s.id <> s.parent
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
order by sort --or by sort1 depending on version
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is in terms of my data, but John Cappelletti's answer also helped very much

Answer (score 2):

You missed the part where you need to identify the depth is from the cte

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    id
    , parent
    , 0 AS depth
FROM
    @sections
WHERE
    id=parent

UNION ALL

SELECT
    s.id
    , s.parent
    , c.depth + 1
FROM
    @sections s
    JOIN CTE c ON s.parent=c.id AND s.id <> s.parent
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps but it doesn't quite give me the results I was looking for. This returns sections in order of section id 1,2,3,...,10. The order I am expecting is 1 6 7 8 10 9 2 3 4 5

Comment: In TSQL, the only way you can guarantee the order of the output dataset is by using an ORDER BY clause. And in this case, I don't know how to produce that given what you stated. A cursor to loop over the ID, but that become a whole different problem.

Answer (score 2):

During the recursive build, it is a small matter to add a sequence.  In the example below, the order is driven by the alphabetical order of the title, but you can use any other available key/sequence.

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,Pt int,Title varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values (0,null,'Tags'),(1,0,'Transportation'),(2,1,'Boats'),(3,1,'Cars'),(4,1,'Planes'),(5,1,'Trains'),(6,0,'Technology'),(7,6,'FTP'),(8,6,'HTTP'),(9,0,'Finance'),(10,9,'FTP'),(11,9,'401K'),(12,2,'Sail'),(13,2,'Powered'),(14,6,'Internet'),(15,6,'Database'),(16,15,'SQL Server'),(17,15,'MySQL'),(18,15,'MS Access')

Declare @Top  int = null          --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 9
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='   '  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteHB (Seq,ID,Pt,Lvl,Title) as (
    Select  Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by Title) as varchar(500))
           ,ID
           ,Pt
           ,Lvl=1
           ,Title 
     From   @Table 
     Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(Pt,-1) else ID end
     Union  All
     Select Seq  = cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.Title)) as varchar(500))
           ,cteCD.ID
           ,cteCD.Pt,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.Title 
     From   @Table cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.Pt = cteHB.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select Hier='HierName'
      ,B.R1  
      ,C.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Title = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl) + A.Title
      --,A.Seq               --<< Normally Excluded, but you can see how the sequence is built
 From cteHB A
 Join cteR1 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Join cteR2 C on A.ID=C.ID
 Order By A.Seq              --<< Use R1 if Range Keys are used
```

Returns

```
Hier        R1  R2  ID  Pt      Lvl    Title
HierName    1   19  0   NULL    1      Tags
HierName    2   4   9   0       2         Finance
HierName    3   3   11  9       3            401K
HierName    4   4   10  9       3            FTP
HierName    5   12  6   0       2         Technology
HierName    6   9   15  6       3            Database
HierName    7   7   18  15      4               MS Access
HierName    8   8   17  15      4               MySQL
HierName    9   9   16  15      4               SQL Server
HierName    10  10  7   6       3            FTP
HierName    11  11  8   6       3            HTTP
HierName    12  12  14  6       3            Internet
HierName    13  19  1   0       2         Transportation
HierName    14  16  2   1       3            Boats
HierName    15  15  13  2       4               Powered
HierName    16  16  12  2       4               Sail
HierName    17  17  3   1       3            Cars
HierName    18  18  4   1       3            Planes
HierName    19  19  5   1       3            Trains
```

Now, you may have noticed R1 and R2.  These are my range keys, and are often used to aggregate data without recursion.  If you don't need or want these, just remove the cteR1 and cteR2 (and the corresponding references in the final SELECT).

> EDIT

You also have the option of selecting a portion of the hierarchy (i.e. Technology and its children).